# Vba code to compare columns that have cells containing dates and paste specific text to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit lost.. I am trying to create a macro that will compare the cells of column AH with the cells of column AH (BOTH COLUMNS contain DATES) and according to the result, it will print a text to the cells of the column AI. The code is below.. everytime I run it, it says Error 13-Type Mismatch and it highlights the line "FirstDate = Cells(RowNumber, 33)". Can you please help me figure this out..

```
 Sub Dates()

    Sheets("1").Select
    Dim Result As Long, RowNumber As Long
    Dim FirstDate As Date, SecondDate As Date

    RowNumber = 2

    Do Until Cells(RowNumber, 2) = ""

    FirstDate = Cells(RowNumber, 33)
    SecondDate = Cells(RowNumber, 34)
    Result = DateDiff("n", FirstDate, SecondDate)

    If Result <= 30 Then
    Cells(RowNumber, 35) = "On Time"
    ElseIf Result > 30 Then
    Cells(RowNumber, 35) = "Late"
    End If

    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

    Loop

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason is that the value in Cells(RowNumber, 33) isn't a date. Excel stores dates a numbers. Change the Numberformat to "General". If you see a number in the cell it's a date. If you see text it's text. If the text looks like a date Excel may be able to coerce it into a proper date (meaning a number). Try `FirstDate = Cdate(Cells(RowNumber, 33).Value)`.

If you set the cell's Numberformat to `Date` you will be able to enter a short date (as defined in your Regional Settings) and Excel will record it as a real date (meaning as a number). It's always better to record dates as "real" dates rather than what you can read as a date.

Counter-intuitive? That's Excel. :-)

Comment: Thank you for you answer too :) indeed it was in a text format... I went and changed the type to data and I put the right form but when I run it again it says type mismatch for FirstDate = Cdate(Cells(RowNumber, 33).Value). too! What else can I do? Any other ideas ?

Comment: The CDate() function requires a string. If your cell now has a real date you should be able to assign it to a variable of Date type without conversion.

Comment: well the problem is that even if I change the format of the cells to date, it changes back after I close the macro. Is there a way to add a line of code in vba to run every time inside the macro and change the format? The macro uses vlookup to get the dates that I compare and I want to make sure that no matter what the source format is, the macro is going to work :)

Comment: How do you enter your dates? First, look at your regional settings. Find out what is the format for entering a "Short date". The format a blank cell as Date with the format "dd mmmm, yyyy". Next, enter a date in that cell in the set "Short date" format, for example 15/8/17. The cell should display "15 August, 2017". Now that cell contains a "real" date and it shouldn't change back to anything else. You can change the display format to anything else, for example "dddd" and it will display "Tuesday", and still the cell's value is the same date value, a number, which you can use in calculations.

Comment: Now the only problem left is to be able to compare two dates and print their difference in hours and minutes... do you have any clue about this?

Comment: The comparison is done but I dont want only a on time or late.. I want the actual difference in hours and minutes

Comment: Now you have numbers you can calculate: Time/Date_Value(1) - Time/Date_Value(2) = Time lapsed. To visualise show the result in a cell formatted as "General". You may see something like 1.34567891 or 0.234567812. The value is expressed in days. Multiply with 24 to convert to hours. So, you get 5.62963 hours. 5.62963 - INT(5.62963) = 0.62963. Multiply with 60 to get minutes. The rest is seconds. However, you may not need that. You can format a cell containing the value 0.234567812 as Time "hh:mm" and it will display hours and minutes. Days will be dropped however. Show > 24 hours only.

Comment: Dim myresult As Long, myrownumber As Long
    Dim FifthDate As Variant, SixthDate As Variant
    Sheets("Tracker1").Select
    myrownumber = 2
    Do Until Cells(myrownumber, 2) = ""
    FifthDate = Cells(myrownumber, 38).Value
    SixthDate = Cells(myrownumber, 37).Value
    If IsDate(FifthDate) And IsDate(SixthDate) Then
    myresult = DateDiff("n", FifthDate, SixthDate)
    If myresult = DateDiff("n", FifthDate, SixthDate) Then
    Cells(myrownumber, 44).Value = "=myresult"
    End If
    End If
    myrownumber = myrownumber + 1
    Loop

Comment: My code is this one !! what would I change to show me the result?

Comment: Is this the same code you published in your original question? If not, please add it to the question so that I can see it in code format. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure that looking at your code will help, however. The problem is from your data, at least in part. I asked you how you enter the dates. I told you how to check if your dates are words or numbers. You didn't reply. Perhaps you can study how Excel handles dates. Find a way to face this problem. Otherwise a solution will be very elusive.

Comment: I am sorry I did not reply! Your solution was correct! I did figure out how to make make the format date! I did it for everything and now it works fine! The result is in minutes now! So it works fine! the final thing that is left to do is make 376 minutes to 6 hours and  16 minutes. Otherwise my problem is solved. Its this final detail! So not to bother you any more I am posting only the final part of the code that I try to use to convert minutes to hours and minutes. In AR column I now have the difference between the dates that we figured out and its correct. I want to make it into hh:mm

Comment: With Range("AR2:AR" & lastrow)
    .Formula = "=TRUNC(AR2/60)&":"&IF(ROUND(((AR2/60-TRUNC(AR2/60))*60),0)=0,"00",ROUND(((AR2/60-TRUNC(AR2/60))*60),0))"
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
    .Value = .Value
    End With

Comment: the formula is working if I put it manually in the cell but when I put in the code its not ..

Comment: Sorry! Didn't mean to leave you alone. Just was busy elsewhere. 376 minutes = 0.26111110944 days. If you have this value in A1 and you format the cell as "dd/mm/yyyy hh"mm" you will see 30/12/1899 06:16. Your 6 hours and 16 minutes are there but the date is bothering. Therefore remove the date from the format. Format the cell as "hh:mm" and it will display 06:16 while its value remains exactly the same. I suggest that you do the calculation in VBA and assign the result to the cell's Value property. That is more transparent than writing the formula to the cell. Faster, too, and easier to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim Result As Long, RowNumber As Long
    Dim FirstDate As Variant, SecondDate As Variant

    Sheets("1").Select

    RowNumber = 2

    Do Until Cells(RowNumber, 2) = ""

        FirstDate = Cells(RowNumber, 33).Value
        SecondDate = Cells(RowNumber, 34).Value

        If IsDate(FirstDate) Then
            Result = DateDiff("n", FirstDate, SecondDate)

            If Result <= 30 Then
                Cells(RowNumber, 35) = "On Time"
            ElseIf Result > 30 Then
                Cells(RowNumber, 35) = "Late"
            End If
        Else
            Cells(RowNumber, 35) = "Not A Valid Date"
        End If

        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately it now says that Result = DateDiff("n", FirstDate, SecondDate) has a type mismatch ... Any idea what I should do ??

Comment: Did you fix the SecondDate? Your code only asks about the FirstDate. Why not the second? `If IsDate(FirstDate) And IsDate(SecondDate) Then` would check both. Not that it could correct the error. Insert `MsgBox Format(FirstDate, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")` and the same for SecondDate, just to see what you are feeding the DateDiff function. Type mismatch indicates that the "dates" you have aren't true dates.

Comment: well the problem is that even if I change the format of the cells to date, it changes back after I close the macro. Is there a way to add a line of code in vba to run every time inside the macro and change the format? The macro uses vlookup to get the dates that I compare and I want to make sure that no matter what the source format is, the macro is going to work :)